# android button with background and text,text not seems completely

Tags: android, button, text, background

My button has a background image and text,but some of the text does not appear.
If i delete android:background=.... line, text seems good.

How can i correct this ?

Thanks much

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_game_bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_word7"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_word9"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_level"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="NORMAL"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Can you clarify **some of the text does not appear**?  Perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: text is "NORMAL" but text's visible part on the button is "NO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is 9patch image file.Seems 9patch file corrupted.

Comment: hey i m facing same problem.. did you revamp ur nine patch image file ? how u solved

Answer (score 0):

You've set the text color to white. Is your `android:background="@drawable/button_level"` background also white as well and for whatever reason only covers the `RMAL` part?

A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: my background color is yellow,i tried changing text color but it didnt work

Comment: Could you try changing your background color to **#E6FFFFFF**. It's white with an alpha component.

Answer (score 0):

Is the drawable resource a bitmap or some xml file? If it is a bitmap, perhaps it'd help if you defined your drawable in xml instead like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Then refer to that xml drawable as your background.

Comment: i found the problem,but i cant understand why this is so.my background image is a 9patch png, i changed it with a normal button background,text seems good

Comment: perhaps your 9-patch image is malformed?